# How to create a word frequency plot using matplotlib or any other library

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with tokenized strings/words. Here is what it looks like. (I'm basically reading a xlsx file and then normalizing the text by removing stop-words, punctuation and so on...)

```
0 [apple, orange, banana...]
1 [banana, apple, date..]
2 [banana, apple, orange...]
```

Now I'm trying to plot a plot for 10 most frequent words using code below.

```
counter = Counter(above_datafarme)
data_words = counter.keys()
words_counts = counter.values()
indexes = np.arange(len(data_words))
width = 0.7
plt.bar(indexes, words_counts, width)
plt.xticks(indexes + width * 0.5, data_words)
plt.show()
```

However, this just throws a unhashable type: 'list' error.

If I convert the dataframe to string using to_string function it creates a plot but just of letters. How do i fix this?

```
counter = Counter(above_datafarme.to_string())
data_words = counter.keys()
words_counts = counter.values()
indexes = np.arange(len(data_words))
width = 0.7
plt.bar(indexes, words_counts, width)
plt.xticks(indexes + width * 0.5, data_words)
plt.show()
```

Forgot to add. How do I customize the code above for just 10 most frequent words?

EDIT.
I tried nltk FreqDist and same result. It just plots the letters.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do that is to create a word frequency table and make a plot after sorting values in there.
The following code covers both creating the frequency table and plotting the chart.

1. Create a counter for the frequency table

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter()

for text in txt.split():
    cnt[text] += 1
# See most common ten words
cnt.most_common(10)
```

2. Create a frequency table

```
import pandas as pd
word_freq = pd.DataFrame(cnt.most_common(15),
                             columns=['words', 'count'])
word_freq.head()
```

3. Create the plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))

# Plot horizontal bar graph
word_freq.sort_values(by='count').plot.barh(x='words',
                      y='count',
                      ax=ax,
                      color="brown")
ax.set_title("Common Words Found")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried in a dataframe way to plot, and works.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame({'c1':['apple','banana','banana'],'c2':['orange','apple','apple'],'c3':['banana','date','orange']})

df_stack=df.stack(level=0) 
counter=df_stack.value_counts() # set top 10: df_stack.value_counts()[0:10]
plt.bar(counter.index,counter.values)
```

[image]

Comment: I get "unhashable type: 'list'" error for counter=df_stack.value_counts(). I just passed my dataframe to it. df=pd.DataFrame(df['key])

Comment: my code is exactly as shown in original post. I've also posted the output of my dataframe in original post. It just has list of words tokens per line. That 0 1 and 2 is just row number and not in the data.